# UITableView Cells with Formatted Text Parsed from an XML

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsxmlparser

I am Parsing an XML file from a URL using an `NSXMLParser`, the items that I parse are added to an array that a `UITableView` loads its data from. Among other things I am parsing titles for events and dates that those events take place on. These items are parsed and added to an array called `stories`. My goal is to have the title of an event be the main text for each cell in my TableView and the date be a subtitle. The title of each event does not need to be formatted (i.e. if the XML file reads: "Event One" then that is what should be displayed) I am successful with this using this method:

(`title` being the title of an item in the XML, `stories` being the array that the TableView loads its data from.)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
        reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell
    NSUInteger storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];

    return cell;
}
```

However I do need to format all of the dates I parse, I do so with an `NSDateFormatter`, I am satisfied with the format of the dates after the `NSDateFormatter` has done its job. If i did not need to format the dates I could use:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"isodate"];
```

to achieve my goal. Once the `NSDateFormatter` has done its job I have a variable (a `NSMutableString`) called `currentDate` with the string value for my formatted dates, using the console I can see that this yields the desired result for every item in the XML. When I use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = currentDate;
```

I end up with every cell in my table having the date of the final item in the XML file (granted it looks nice is formatted correctly). I have tried moving my methods around to no avail. If you wouldn't mind pointing me in the right direction, I need to know how to include the value of my variable `currentDate` in the subtitle text of a `UITableView` in a way in which the title of an item and the date of the item in a cell correspond with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Regarding your date problem, it sounds like you're storing the date in a single instance variable called `currentDate`. And given that you didn't share that code, I gather you're not doing that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but rather, perhaps in your parser, or something like that. Unfortunately, that would give every cell in the table the date for the last row you parsed). You should either

   - call your date formatting right in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (or, better, call a method that does your date formatting), specifically grab `[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"isodate"]`, format it, and set `detailTextLabel.text` accordingly; or
   - rather than storing the formatted date in a single `currentDate` variable, add an dictionary key for the formatted date and store it in the mutable dictionary with everything else you parsed from the XML (e.g. read in `isodate`, format a string and save it back to the same dictionary with a unique key, maybe `formattedDate`).
2. `NSUInteger storyIndex = indexPath.row;` is a more common syntax if you're grabbing the news item associated with the given row of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your parse data into an **NSDictionary** with ***Key - value pair***. Here you can use title  as key and date as value and by this way both data will be corresponding to each one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line

```
NSUInteger storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
```

you should be using indexPath.row instead,

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
```